# Char array unexpected null character

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
char *placeDelimiter(char message[], int maxSize) {
  int msgSize = strlen(message);  //length of message
  int delSize = (msgSize/maxSize);//how many delimiters are needed
  int remSize = msgSize%maxSize;  //remainder characters
  int newSize = msgSize+delSize;  //new size of message
  if (remSize==0) delSize--;      //if there are no remainders remove , from end

  char *temp = (char *)malloc(newSize+1);
  int delPos = 0;
  int spacing = 0;
  for (int x=0;x<msgSize;x++) {
    if (delPos==maxSize) {
        temp[x] = ',';
        delPos=0;spacing++;
    } else {delPos++;}
    temp[x+spacing] = message[x];
    printf("Char: %c DelPos: %d Spacing: %d\n", temp[x], delPos, spacing);
  }
  temp[msgSize] = '\0';
  return temp;
}
```

The above is a function that places a delimiter every set number of characters (`maxSize`)

When the funciton is given in input such as `"This is a message"` along with `4` for `maxSize` then the output should be `"This, is ,a me,ssag,e"`. However there is an issue which is giving null characters during the loop of which obviously acts as the end of the character array

I added in the printf in the loop to provide more information during the process and this is the output given:

```
Char: T DelPos: 1 Spacing: 0
Char: h DelPos: 2 Spacing: 0
Char: i DelPos: 3 Spacing: 0
Char: s DelPos: 4 Spacing: 0
Char: , DelPos: 0 Spacing: 1
Char:   DelPos: 1 Spacing: 1
Char: i DelPos: 2 Spacing: 1
Char: s DelPos: 3 Spacing: 1
Char:   DelPos: 4 Spacing: 1
Char: , DelPos: 0 Spacing: 2
Char:  DelPos: 1 Spacing: 2
Char:   DelPos: 2 Spacing: 2
Char: m DelPos: 3 Spacing: 2
Char: e DelPos: 4 Spacing: 2
Char: , DelPos: 0 Spacing: 3
Char: s DelPos: 1 Spacing: 3
Char:  DelPos: 2 Spacing: 3
This, is ,
```

The character after the second comma is null and I can not find a reason for it. Does any one have any ideas why?

Comment: Well, your last `temp[msgSize] = '\0';` should be`temp[msgSize+spacing] = '\0';`, but I'm not sure if that justifies the result.

Comment: @rodrigo spacing is done to justify commas and msgSize is meant to take that into account already

Comment: `msgSize` is set to `strlen(message)` and never modified again. The last valid char written to `temp` is `temp[x+spacing]` and in the last iteration `x == msgSize-1`, so the next-to-last character of `temp` must be `msgSize + spacing` (or `newSize` maybe?), that is where the NUL char should be.

Comment: @rodrigo oh sorry yes I was thinking of newSize, let me try that

Comment: @rodrigo same outcome still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this code. One

```
temp[x] = ',';
```

should be:

```
temp[x + spacing] = ',';
```

because that is where the character would be if the condition is false.

And two, is the NUL I talked in the comments:

```
temp[msgSize] = '\0';
```

should be:

```
temp[msgSize + spacing] = '\0';
```

IMO, it would be easier to understand if you used two index variables instead of an offset. Something like:

```
for (x = 0, y = 0; x < msgSize; ++x, ++y)
{
    if (...)
      temp[y++] = ',';
    temp[y] = message[x]; 
}
temp[y] = '\0';
```

PS: You should try and use a debugger, it makes some things easier...